# Force font formatting in a contenteditable div

Tags: html

How would i force font formatting in a contenteditable div,e.g. so if the user were to paste italic'd or bolded text into my div, how do i make it not display the text in italic or bold and just display it in normal non formatted text?

i want to preserve tabs and whitespace though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need JavaScript or jQuery to do that. Here's a jQuery solution:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('blur keyup paste', function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text());
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mcTnr/)**.